# Buttons not aligned properly

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am teaching myself. Ionic Framework and using Angular to make a calculator app. The last row of buttons I cannot get align. I have tried changing the columns, and I've put the <kbd>=</kbd> button in the last row but still cannot get it to align properly. Any advice would help so much. Thank you.

HTML

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <div class="calc-main">
    <div class="calc-display">
      <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="display" class="ion-text-end"></ion-input>
    </div>
    <ion-grid class="button-grid">
      <!-- Row 1 -->
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round"   *ngIf="!isc" (click)="click('ac')" class="reset-button">AC</ion-button>
          <ion-button shape="round"   *ngIf="isc" (click)="click('c')" class="reset-button">C</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round"  (click)="click('%')" class="operator-button">%</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round"  (click)="click('/')" class="operator-button">/</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round"  (click)="click('x')" class="operator-button">x</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <!-- Row 2 -->
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round" (click)="click('7')" class="number-button">7</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round" (click)="click('8')" class="number-button">8</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round" (click)="click('9')" class="number-button">9</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round" (click)="click('-')" class="operator-button">-</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <!-- Row 3 -->
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round" (click)="click('4')" class="number-button">4</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round" (click)="click('5')" class="number-button">5</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round" (click)="click('6')" class="number-button">6</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round" (click)="click('+')" class="operator-button">+</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <!-- Row 4 -->
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round" (click)="click('1')" class="number-button">1</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round" (click)="click('2')" class="number-button">2</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round" (click)="click('3')" class="number-button">3</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <!-- Row 5 -->
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round"  (click)="click('0')" class="double-width">0</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round"  (click)="click('.')" class="operator-button">.</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button shape="round" (click)="click('=')" class= "double-height">=</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

CSS

```
.calc-main {
  background-color: #ad0fc2;
  height: 100%;
}

.calc-display {
  background-color: #ad0fc2;
  padding: 60px 15px 20px;
}

ion-input {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 48px;
}

ion-col {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  
}

ion-button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.button-grid {
  height: 500px;
  width:  250px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.double-width {
  width: 100px;

}

.double-height {
  height: 100px;
 
}
```

Here is what it is doing: I need the equal button to slide up and the three buttons above to slide over.

[image: current output]

Comment: This is just a wild guess, as I'm not familiar with this framework, but what happens if you put the "=" button in row 4?

Comment: It ends up pushing row 5 down and leaves a large gap. I also tried making putting the last column in its own column that that just made it all crazy.

Comment: can you put the full html and the css?

Comment: I just added all the HTML and my CSS

Comment: Could you make a stackblitz of this?

Comment: use Flex box to achieve this. Ion-row will always go to next line. or if you still wanna use ion-grid. you can add `=` to row 4. and `margin-top: -50px` (or what ever the number) to row 5.